# Variance of a function of a random variable

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

For a random variable $X$ we know that $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E^2(X)$. If we think of a measurable function $g(X)$, since we can calculate $E(g(X^2))$ and $E^2(g(X))$ would it also be true that $Var(g(X)) = E(g(X^2)) - E^2(g(X))$ for any $g$?

Comment: I assume X is a scalar rather than a vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at $Y=g(X)$ as another random variable and use the definition of the variance to obtain the following formula:
$$Var(g(X))=E[g(X)^2]- E[g(X)]^2$$

Be careful your square was misplaced !

Comment: Was the question edited?  It looks to me that the square is in a proper place for your equations to agree.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I was refering to the square in $E[g(X^2)]$